# RobotFramework with Python's asyncio

Tags: python, robotframework, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I'm trying to run RobotFramework with Python3.6's asyncio.

The relevant Python-Code looks as follows:

```
""" SampleProtTest.py """

import asyncio
import threading

class SubscriberClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    """
    Generic, Asynchronous protocol that allows sending using a synchronous accessible queue
    Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/30940625/4150378
    """
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop

    """ Functions follow for reading... """


class PropHost:
    def __init__(self, ip: str, port: int = 50505) -> None:
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.__coro = self.loop.create_connection(lambda: SubscriberClientProtocol(self.loop), ip, port)
        _, self.__proto = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__coro)
        # run the asyncio-loop in background thread
        threading.Thread(target=self.runfunc).start()

    def runfunc(self) -> None:
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def dosomething(self):
        print("I'm doing something")


class SampleProtTest(object):
    def __init__(self, ip='127.0.0.1', port=8000):
        self._myhost = PropHost(ip, port)

    def do_something(self):
        self._myhost.dosomething()

if __name__=="__main__":
    tester = SampleProtTest()
    tester.do_something()
```

If I run this file in python, it prints, as expected:

```
I'm doing something
```

To run the code in Robot-Framework, I wrote the following .robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Just A Sample
Library           SampleProtTest.py
*** Test Cases ***
Do anything
    do_something
```

But if I run this .robot-file, I get the following error:

```
Initializing test library 'SampleProtTest' with no arguments failed: This event loop is already running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SampleProtTest.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._myhost = PropHost(ip, port)
  File "SampleProtTest.py", line 21, in __init__
    _, self.__proto = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__coro)
  File "appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 454, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 408, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
```

Can someone explain to me why or how I can get around this?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Dandekar I added some Debug outputs, see code above, and get the following output from robot:

```
- Loop until complete...
- Starting Thread...
- Running in thread...
==============================================================================
Sample :: Just A Sample                                                       
==============================================================================
Do anything                                                           - Loop until complete...
| FAIL |
Initializing test library 'SampleProtTest' with no arguments failed: This event loop is already running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\share\TestAutomation\SampleProtTest.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._myhost = PropHost(ip, port)
  File "C:\share\TestAutomation\SampleProtTest.py", line 24, in __init__
    _, self.__proto = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__coro)
  File "c:\users\muechr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 454, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "c:\users\muechr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 408, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sample :: Just A Sample                                               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\share\TestAutomation\results\output.xml
Log:     C:\share\TestAutomation\results\log.html
Report:  C:\share\TestAutomation\results\report.html
```

As I see it, the problem is that it already started the Thread BEFORE the test case. Oddly, if I remove the line

```
_, self.__proto = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__coro)
```

It seems to run through - but I can't explain why... But this is not a practical solution as I'm not able to access __proto like this...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Comment out the part where your code runs at start

```
# if __name__=="__main__":
#    tester = SampleProtTest()
#    tester.do_something()
```

That piece gets run when you import your script in robot framework (causing the port to be occupied).

Also: If you are simply trying to run keywords asynchronously, there is a library that does that (although I have not tried it myself).

[robotframework-async](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-async/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, but it would be nice in my case to use the "regular" robotframework only, to be able to continous read in Python from the IP and request the sending / analysis from RobotFramework.

Comment: I do not have access to asyncio due to my python version, but from your code, I would say, that you can simply randomize the port and see if that works. `from random import choice` and then where you set the port, `port=choice(range(8000,9000))`. If this works, then you can enhance the code to make the port truly random.

Comment: Actually, I think I have found the issue. Comment out the autorun portion of the code. `if __name__ ==...`

Comment: Please excuse, I completely oversaw your posts - thank you very much! Unfortunately, it did not help.
The `if __name__...` section gets not executed in Robot Framework. If I add 
`from robot.api import logger
...
if __name__=="__main__":
    logger.console("- Hello world :-)")
...
`
I do not see the "Hello world"-message when executing Robot Framework.

Comment: Since I do not have access to or the ability to add asyncio, I cannot replicate this one at work. Will try to replicate at home and see what the error is. But the thread does start and occupy the port before your test is run, so at least the problem has been identified.