# Calling async function from asyncio Protocol

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose we have some asyncio Protocol running. And I need, for example, create Transport to specific socket adress from Protocol handler.

This operation is async. But protocol handler is an ordinary function. We cannot call something like `run_until_complete`, because loop is already running.

Is there any way to solve this? I hope there is something cleaner, than creating another Task with Queue to it.

Comment: simple approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126340/calling-a-coroutine-from-asyncio-protocol-data-received and more advance one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746619/calling-coroutines-in-asyncio-protocol-data-received (with comment why)

Comment: @kwarunek Thanks! Now I see, my question is a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe somebody find this topic useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937042/asyncio-persisent-client-protocol-class-using-queue/30940625#30940625

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a coroutine from asyncio.Protocol.data\_received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126340/calling-a-coroutine-from-asyncio-protocol-data-received)